# select a single word at a screen coordinate (x, y) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I wonder if there's a way to select a single word in a HTML by providing a screen coordinate (x,y). Basically I'd like to have a customized window.getSelection, but instead of triggered by the cursor(or touch), a (x, y) point will be the input. Thanks.

Comment: You can use .offSet() function. http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: @Anonymous0day, elementFromPoint() only gives me the entire element, not a specific word.

Comment: oups you are right !

Comment: @DinoMyte could you explain a little more? How can I get the selected word using offset()? Thanks

Comment: I try once again : you have to use [caretPositionFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretPositionFromPoint)

Comment: Can you provide some code you have tested ?

Answer (score 0):

One ***BASIC*** solution could be something like that :
*( the detection of word are based on one space ' ' strictly ) !*
Only for demonstration purpose, encodage and non alphabetics characters  are here out of scope !

```js
var $j = function(val, space) {return JSON.stringify(val, '', space || '');};
var $l = function(val) {document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><pre>' + val + '</pre></div>')};
$lj = function(val, space) {$l($j(val, space));};





function getWordAtPosition(x,y){
  var caretPosition = document.caretPositionFromPoint( x , y );

  var str = caretPosition.offsetNode.data;
  var len = caretPosition.offsetNode.length;
  var pos = caretPosition.offset;
  
  var result = {
    function: 'getWordAtPosition( ' + x + ' , ' + y + ')' ,
    x       : x ,
    y       : y ,
    data    : str ,
    startAt : pos ,
    endAt   : pos ,
    curChar : str[pos] ,
  };
  
    
    
    if(!result.curChar) return result;
    if( result.curChar === " ") return result;
    
    
    while(pos>=0 && str[pos]!==' ') pos--;
    result.startAt = pos+1;
    
    var endAt = str.indexOf(' ' , result.startAt);
    endAt = endAt === -1 || endAt === result.startAt ? len-1 : endAt-1;
    result.endAt = endAt;
    
    result.word = str.substring(result.startAt , result.endAt+1);
  
  $lj( result , ' ');
}



document.onclick = function(evt) {
  
  getWordAtPosition(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);

};
```

```html
Click anywhere in this document.
<div>
  <p>Testing my code here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  Anonymous0day. Appreciate your answer, but does caretPositionFromPoint (or  elementFromPoint()) have to be bound to an event?

Comment: not necessarly ! see my example, i just get pointer coordinates from event and i pass them to the function ! you can use the function without the event, in the output i have added the function that should be called with the coordinate, if you try it in your debugger you will obtain the same result without event

Comment: if you use my test case you can call the function to get the word "anywhere" using `getWordAtPosition( 98 , 15);` without any event